# Cloudkitty - Rating display issue

Tags: openstack, devstack, ceilometer

In my Devstack setup there was a issue in displaying details in the Rating section.

Pricing was configured correctly, During Instance creation Rate is displayed in the instance creation window.

But after creation of instance I am checking the Rating section for rates or cost.

It was not displaying the value as needed.

I checked the DB table (rated_data_frames) in Cloudkitty.

It doesn't have the necessary values immediately.

I was continuously checking for some hours consecutively.

But I can be able to see that Cloudkitty DB is getting updated with the values after some hours from instance creation.

That is after some hours, it is getting added in table regarding the Instance created.

So that in Front-end also it got displayed.

I want to know why it is happening.

**Is there any solution for the same to get the results immediately.
Simply I need to get the results immediately in rating section.**

I can be able to see that in cloudkitty.conf file section is there as follows:

```
# Rating period in seconds. (integer value)
#period = 3600
#wait_periods = 2
```

If changing this will help us.?